# Run LIKE query with optional parameters - SQLite3

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, electron

I'm creating an electron application that uses [`better-sqlite3`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-sqlite3) and I wanted to know, in general, if there was a way to run a query that uses `LIKE` with optional parameters? Let's say there's a table people that contains the columns firstname and lastname. A user could search by:

Firstname only in which case the query would be:

`SELECT * from people WHERE firstname LIKE %userEnteredFname%`

Lastname only in which case the query would be:

`SELECT * from people WHERE lastname LIKE %userEnteredLname%`

Or both fields:

`SELECT * from people WHERE firstname LIKE %userEnteredFname% AND lastname LIKE %userEnterLname%`

And just FYI, there's a way to `INSERT` with optional parameters:

```
const stmt = db.prepare('INSERT INTO cats (name, age) VALUES (?, ?)');
const info = stmt.run('Joey'); //age would be null
```

The query depends on which search parameter is entered. Sure enough you can prepare statements for a small number of input fields but I have about 7 and there can be a lot of combinations there.

Comment: `(X LIKE '%' +?1+'%' OR ?1 IS NULL) AND (Y LIKE '%' +?2+'%' OR ?2 IS NULL) AND... So on`... Then put all parameters or nulls where is not entered

Comment: @Selvin what's `?1`   ?

Comment: [SQL Parameters](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `userEnterLname` is an empty string,

```
 SELECT * from people WHERE firstname LIKE %userEnteredFname% AND lastname LIKE %userEnterLname%
```

is the same as

```
 SELECT * from people WHERE lastname LIKE %userEnteredLname%
```

So just keep the extra variables empty unless you want to search them.

Answer (score 2):

The operator `LIKE` returns `NULL` when any of its operands is `NULL`.
So for all the columns use `COALESCE()` which will return `1` (= `TRUE`) in case the value passed is `NULL`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM people 
WHERE COALESCE(firstname LIKE '%' || ? || '%', 1) 
  AND COALESCE(lastname LIKE '%' || ? || '%', 1)
```

The `?` placeholders stand for the parameters that you will pass to the query.